# An academic "hello world" on Monero

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, mining-hardware, monero-research-lab

I'm a graduate student looking to improve my skills in real-world applications of cryptography and online anonymity. Reviewing all of the new blockchain and alt-coin variants, I believe that Monero is the most interesting development in this respect.

I'm skilled in software development, microcontroller DSP, and GP-GPU high-performance computing, relating to academic research in number theory.

What recommendations would you have on how I can best (and most rapidly) familiarize myself with the Monero development community?

I'm considering starting an open-source project for mining on Android devices (even with the inherent computational inefficiencies) as a proof-of-skill mechanism. I know of the ARMv7 code on the main branch, but is there any other relevant projects?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems too open ended for Stack Exchange. This thread is a good place to start: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/766jwa/list_of_sources_you_need_to_comprehend_monero_and/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What recommendations would you have on how I can best (and most rapidly) familiarize myself with the Monero development community?

From a dev perspective, the best places to start are probably the IRC channels #monero-dev and #monero-research-lab, both of which have regular meetings and discussion. There are also open the issues and pull requests on GitHub for seeing things actively being proposed, fixed or worked on.

> I'm considering starting an open-source project for mining on Android devices (even with the inherent computational inefficiencies) as a proof-of-skill mechanism. I know of the ARMv7 code on the main branch, but is there any other relevant projects?

Monero certainly builds and runs on Android fine; there are instructions for compilation (inc. armv6, armv7 & armv8) in the main [project page](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#on-linux-for-android-using-docker). It's difficult to answer your question w.r.t. other relevant projects without knowing more specifics, but there are certainly others adding Monero mining capabilities to phones, such as an recent news about HTC launching a phone that will be shipped with a Monero miner [[src](https://www.theblockcrypto.com/post/61529/htc-to-allow-mining-monero-directly-via-its-exodus-blockchain-phone)].